# When​ deriving SHM equation we take the integrating constant as initial phase. How we know that this integrating constant represent initial phase?

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

*the derivation:*

$F=-ky$

$m\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=-ky$

since $\frac{k}{m} = ω^2$

$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} + ω^2y=0$  -------> (1)

now eqn (1)*2($\frac{dy}{dt}$) we get

$2\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} + 2yω^2\frac{dy}{dt}= 0$

now integrating we get

$\frac{dy}{dt}^2 = -ω^2y^2 +C$ --------->(2)

when $y = a$ (amplitude) 
then $\frac{dy}{dt} = 0$

$C = a^2ω^2$

substituting value of $C$ in (2)

$\frac{dy}{dt} =\omega \sqrt (a^2 - y^2)$

now integrating we get

$sin^{-1}(\frac{y}{a}) = ωt + Ø$

$y = asin(wt + Ø)$

where Ø is the integrating constant and
it represents the initial phase.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how we know that the integrating constant found in the end of the derivation is the phase difference

Comment: Well, it's a constant right? And it's inside a $sin()$ function, so it has to be an angle. And what happens if you take some trigonometric function and add a constant angle to it's argument?

Comment: By definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_(waves)

Comment: What didn't satisfy you about my explanation?

Comment: If we take a constant angle to its argument we simply get a value like if we give 60° to a sine function we get ✓3/2 but that doesn't prove that 60° is the initial phase.

Comment: It's a translation, $f(x+c)$ -> $f(x)$ translated left along the x axis by $c$.

Comment: Sorry I finally understand what are you trying say. Thank you very much Phase.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $y(t)=a\sin(\omega t + \phi)$, let's find the initial displacement (i.e. at $t=0$):

$$y(0)=a\sin(\phi)$$

So the initial value of the function is not zero, but rather some value dependent upon the parameter $\phi$. This parameter is the argument of a trig function, so it represents an angle. Since at $t=0$ (the initial state), the trig function is accepting an angle of $\phi$, then $\phi$ can rightly be called the "initial angle". "Phase" in this context is just another word for angle.

If that logic isn't clear, here's another way to think about it: Take any function $f(x)$, and let's add a number $c$ to the argument of the function to obtain $f(x+c)$. What effect does this modification have on the graph of $f$? It "shifts the curve" left $c$ units. This is a *function transformation*, specifically a *leftward translation*. Note that the initial function value, that is at $x=0$, is $f(c)$. Thus the shifting parameter $c$ specifies the initial value.  So what would all this mean for our sine wave? I think these diagrams should drive the point home:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your solution, $\phi$ is clearly an initial phase as integrating constants are usually initial conditions, and as you have shown, it is an integrating constant which ends up inside of the sine function (therefore it is a phase by nature of the fact that it is in the sine function). Together it means $\phi$ is a fit parameter that is the initial phase as at $t=0$, $y=asin(\phi)$.

A different outlook that made sense to me (I may have just learned things differently) is that we know that we have a phase because the general solution to the second order homogeneous differential equation:
$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} + \omega^2y = 0$
is:
$y(t) = Asin(\omega t) + Bcos(\omega t)$
Where A and B are constants determined by the initial conditions. You can also re-write this solution in terms on sine or cosine with an initial phase because any linear combination (sum) of a sine and a cosine with the same frequency $\omega$ will result in a single plane wave that is simply shifted by a phase. This can be seen through a some trig tricks but the main point is that the sum of these two functions will have the same periodicity. Long story short,  $Asin(\omega t) + Bcos(\omega t) = Csin(wt + \phi)$ can be solved for C and $\phi$ given A and B.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comments above, your equation $(1)$ can be readily solved with an exponential ansatz $y = Ae^{\lambda t}$ from which you find $\lambda = \pm \mathrm{i} \omega$ so that $$y(t) = C \cos \omega t + D \sin \omega t.$$ This is a superposition of two linearly independent functions with a common frequency $\omega$ so we can rewrite $$C \cos \omega t + D \sin \omega t \overset{!}{=} B \sin (\omega t + \phi)$$ from which you find that $\phi$ must satisfy $$\begin{cases} B \cos \phi = D \\ B \sin \phi = C \end{cases} \,\,\,\,\Rightarrow \,\,\,\,\,\tan \phi = \frac{C}{D}$$

But $C$ and $D$ are related to the *initial* conditions $y(0)$ and $\dot{y}(0)$ by simply $y(0)=  C$ and $\dot{y}(0)/\omega = D$ so that $$\tan \phi = \omega \,\frac{y(0)}{\dot{y}(0)}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(*)$$

In this way, one can use the initial conditions to get the two integration constants $\left\{C,D \right\}$ but through the above rewriting can get equivalent constants $\left\{B, \phi \right\}$ wherein $(*)$ the variable $\phi$ thus has the obvious interpretation of an *initial* phase.

I realise this argument may come across as a bit pedantic but, if you've never used trig functions before, hopefully it's a little clearer to see how all the things relate.